# Best Server for Node.js + Express site

Tags: node.js, express, server, server-administration

I am new in node js, I am developing an app in Node+express+mongo+react. Where Should I host this app for production, How do I manage the server? Like how to check if the site is working well, any error, scalability etc?

Is there any managed server for Node js available in the market? currently, our all servers are VPS with Cpanel installed on Linode, we are running php websites on that, can I use that for node js.

Please help if someone has pushed the site from local to production use with high scalability.

Comment: You don't even need a full-fledged server (or VPS).  You can host your Node app in "the cloud".  Look at [Bluemix](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/01/get-started-building-node-js-bluemix-10-minutes-less/),  [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/).

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 , Is it worth to go with AWS? Will it cost enough then other companies like Digital Ocean ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a hosting service managed by other companies to deploy your node app, the you can use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/) or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs).

Or you can also have a Linux server from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04), but in this case you have to figure how to configure the server.

I also managed to deploy a node app in Windows Server 2016 / IIS using iisnode tool: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

Comment: Hi @Optimist, thanks for the answer, which one is better and not too expensive, I need to finalize today

Comment: In your case, I think you can go for DigitalOcean. The pricing starts from $5.00 per month. Here is the list of pricing: https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/